# Word for an idea that quickly comes to dominate discourse on a particular issue?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes an idea that captures people's attention and quickly eclipses discussions of other ideas related to a particular issue. Incendiary is almost the word, but without the suggestion of inflammatory content.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps 'compelling' would suit?

Answer (score 1):

**hot-button**

> :  an emotional and usually controversial issue or concern that
>   triggers immediate intense reaction

"Hot Button." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 26 Apr. 2016.

**burning** issue or question

> 3: of fundamental importance :  urgent < one of the burning issues of our
>   time>

"Burning." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 26 Apr. 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas that come to mind

**flashpoint**

Full Definition of flash point
1
:  the lowest temperature at which vapors above a volatile combustible substance ignite in air when exposed to flame
2
:  a point at which someone or something bursts suddenly into action or being (Merriam+Webster)

**trigger**

**buzzword**

**gamechanger**

Answer (score 0):

Sockdolager can be used when a statement or action settles, finalizes or concludes anything.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sockdolager

Answer (score 0):

**flame-starter**

in internet slang *flame* is used for a heated discussion, so I tend to use it for any strong opinionated discussion even outside the virtual realm

Answer (score 0):

*Seminal* is possible, but you're looking for something more immediate. You could use *a seminal paper*, but maybe this isn't quite right, either.

*Usurp* could work too, but it has a negative connotation. Similarly for *expropriate*.

*Commandeer*: "Frank's idea commandeered the discussion".

*Momentous*: "Gödel's momentous theorem quickly eclipsed Russel's work".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a phrase rather than single word okay?

**take on a life of its own**

> to no longer be controlled by anyone
>
> *Once an earthquake starts, it takes on a life of its own.*
>
> *Someone imagined it, and the idea took on a life of its own.*
>
> — 
>   [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+on+a+life+of+own)